# Sharing folder between two local users on different machines

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-domain

I'm having a problem that seems trivial, and it used to work just a few weeks ago...

I have two computers on a larger domain. On both computers I have local users with admin privileges.

I want to share one folder on one computer and have it accessible on the other. Seems easy, but it doesn't work.

It does work if I access the folder with a domain-connected user, but not with a local user.

Any ideas? The computer sharing the folder is  Win10, and it's not accessible with either Win7 or Win10 machines.

Comment: Does your domain deploy any policies which would disable NTLM and enforce Kerberos authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the old gotcha that Windows really has two incompatible
sets of network shares for administrators and non-administrators.
Depending on whether the share was created in Administrator mode,
a Windows explorer that is not run in the same mode might not see it.
In addition, network shares established during startup are created in
non-administrator mode.

To work around this problem, set to `1` the `EnableLinkedConnections` registry value,
of type DWORD, under the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`.

This is further described in the Microsoft article
[Some Programs Cannot Access Network Locations When UAC Is Enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee844140%28v=ws.10%29) :

> This value enables Windows Vista and Windows 7 to share network connections between the filtered access token and the full administrator access token for a member of the Administrators group.